# Strange sed output

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

The following command with sed and simple regexp:

```
echo 'Atest Atest Atest' | sed -E 's/A|$/B/g'
```

produces output:

```
Btest Btest B
```

Could someone explain, please, why does sed eat last word? I expected the output to be something like this:

```
Btest Btest BtestB
```

I use sed version bundled with Mac OS ("BSD-flavour").

**Update**
This behaviour looks like a bug, comparing to GNU sed, so I've chosen to stick to the latter one.

Comment: Works fine to me on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`.

Comment: My sed (4.2.2) returns what you expect. It is in zsh under cygwin in windows

Comment: Works for me. sed 4.2.1 works as you expect, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting, this appears to be some bug (weird behavior) in BSD sed available on OSX. I can reproduce this behavior. Looks this behavior happens only with `g` flag.

To fix this I would suggest use this equivalent `sed` command:

```
echo 'Atest Atest Atest' | sed 's/A/B/g;s/$/B/'
Btest Btest BtestB
```

Comment: What does "sed kept on replacing each $ by B" mean?

Comment: `echo 'foo' | sed -E 's/f|$/B/'` becomes `boo` but `echo 'foo' | sed -E 's/f|$/B/g'` becomes `B` on OSX sed.

Comment: Another weird behavior: `echo 'foo' | sed -E 's/^|$/B/g'` becomes `Bfoo` instead of `BfooB`

Comment: Interesting. What about `echo 'foo' | sed -E 's/$/B/'` (with and without the `g` flag)?

Comment: Actually I had tested it too. That gives `fooB` in both cases.

Comment: Yes, I agree, looks like a bug. But actual workaround for me was to install gnu-sed via Homebrew :)

Comment: Yes I also have `gsed` via `homebrew` and that works as expected.